# How can I rerun a line in python

Tags: python

I have this line:

```
id = temp if len(str(temp := int(input('enter id: ')))) == 10 else print('its wrong') # and rerun this line
```

I want if length(input) less than 10 rerun this line and get another input

thanks for helping:)))

Comment: One usually uses a loop when they want to repeat things.

Comment: Guess what - smashing everything into a single line of code isn't always the best way. Now you're seeing that. It was never going to run faster because of it (one-liners don't run faster), and now you can't get a loop in there

Comment: It's an easy trap to fall into. Readability counts and you can always time this stuff out with the `timeit` module but timing won't make any difference here

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
while True:
    id_str = input('enter id: ')
    if len(id_str) == 10 and id_str.isdecimal():
        id_num = int(id_str)
        break
    print('its wrong')

# id_num is now an ten-digit int
```

Comment: yes I can but I want to make it short and optimize

Comment: @frg optimise _what_? There's nothing optimal with your one-liner.

Comment: FYI, `isdecimal()` is more than `0123456789`, e.g., `'0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯൦'.isdecimal()` -> `True`.  Even `int('١٢٣') == 123`.

Comment: Worth noting that these are still valid decimals in different locales, but something to look out for if you only want to allow `0123456789`.